# Change user metadata on registration (show_admin_bar_front = false)

Tags: php, user-meta

This is my first contact with WP Development, and I'm trying to not display the WP admin bar after the registration. Since it's metadata called 'show_admin_bar-front', I'm updating that right after creating the user.

```
 if(count($error) == 0) {
            wp_create_user( $username, $password, $email);
            $user_id = get_current_user_id();
            update_user_meta($user_id, 'show_admin_bar_front', 'false');
            echo "User Created Successfully!";
            exit();
        }
```

As you can see, in the chunk above, I try to get the user ID right after creating the user and then updating the pointed metadata ('true' as default). Probably I'm doing something pretty stupid. Could someone enlighten me? Bellow, the full code.

```
 <?php
    /*
    Template Name: Registration
    */
    get_header();
    global $wpdb;

    if($_POST) {

        $username = $wpdb->escape($_POST['txtUsername']);
        $email = $wpdb->escape($_POST['txtEmail']);
        $password = $wpdb->escape($_POST['txtPassword']);
        $ConfPassword = $wpdb->escape($_POST['txtConfirmPassword']);


    $error = array();
        if(strpos($username, '') !==FALSE) {
            $error['username_space'] = "Username has space!";
        }

        if(empty($username)) {
            $error['username_empty'] = "Username is empty!";
        }

        if(username_exists($username)) {
            $error['username_exists'] = "Username already exists!";
        }

        if(!is_email($email)) {
            $error['email_valid'] = "Please, add a valid e-mail.";
        }

        if(email_exists($email)) {
            $error['email_existence'] = "This e-mail is already registered.";
        }

        if(strcmp($password, $ConfPassword) !==0) {
            $error['password'] = "Password don't match!";
        }

        if(count($error) == 0) {
            wp_create_user( $username, $password, $email);
            $user_id = get_current_user_id();
            update_user_meta($user_id, 'show_admin_bar_front', 'false');
            echo "User Created Successfully!";
            exit();
        } else {
            print_r($error);
        }
    }

    ?>

    <form method="post">

        <p>
            <label>Username</label>
            <div>
                <input type="text" id="txtUsername" name="txtUsername" placeholder="Username"/>
            </div>
        </p>

        <p>
            <label>Email</label>
            <div>
                <input type="email" id="txtEmail" name="txtEmail" placeholder="Email"/>
            </div>
        </p>

        <p>
            <label>Password</label>
            <div>
                <input type="password" id="txtPassword" name="txtPassword" placeholder="Password"/>
            </div>
        </p>

        <p>
            <label>Confirm Password</label>
            <div>
                <input type="password" id="txtConfirmPassword" name="txtConfirmPassword" placeholder="Confirm Password"/>
            </div>
        </p>

        <input type="submit" name="btnSubmit"/>

    </form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to update meta on registration like this I think a better option would be to use the `register_new_user` hook with `add_action`. https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/register_new_user/

So something like:

```php
add_action('register_new_user','my_update_meta',10,1);


function my_update_meta($user_id){

 update_user_meta($user_id, 'show_admin_bar_front', false);


}
```

If in doubt, hooks/filters/actions tend to be the best option for WordPress work.

Comment: Got it! The only thing I didn't understand was the 10,1 after the 2 first parameters. Could you explain to me, please?

Comment: add_action( $hook, $function_to_add, $priority, $accepted_args );

The first number indicates priority. 10 is the default, but if you want the function to be run earlier you could make it lower, or if you want it later you could make it higher. In this case it doesn't make too much difference.

The second number refers to the number of arguments for the function, so in this case just 1 ($user_id).

Have a read of https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_action/ if you're not too familiar with actions etc.